# How to set the label of a button to bold even after tapped?

Tags: ios

I am having a problem to set the label of a button to bold. I set it programmatically and it works, but and I tap the button, the label turns back to normal. What is happening?

Comment: please add your code so that it's possible for people to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that programmatically by setting the label font to bold:

```
yourButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
```

If it did't work when you tap, go to the storyboard and, in the left menu, change the style to default and it should work.